# Navigation Drawer Listview does not update new items even after calling notifyDataSetChange() on Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListView` rendered on a Navigation Drawer.
The content of the list view is provided by my custom adapter (derived from `BaseAdapter`) which appends two arrays one after another like below

```
*@Override
public int getCount() {
  return array1.size() + array2.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (position < array1.size()) 
     // return a view  generated from first array
  }
  else {
     // returns a view generated from the second array
  }
}
```

The ListView is connected to the adapter like this

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Initially right after `onCreate()`, `array2` is empty; only `array1` is populated and rendered on the ListView correctly. Afterwards, after a slight delay, a background thread populates the `array2` and I want the new items to show up on the list. To achieve that, I issue a `notifyDataSetChanged()` to the adapter from the main thread. Unfortunately, this does not update the ListView UI with the new items from the second array. While debugging this, I found out that my `getCount()` method is getting called which is correctly returning the combined array size count, but the `getView()` method is not getting called at all. I ensured that the ListView is not hidden by other overlapping widgets.

Strangely, once I tap on the `ListView`, it gets refreshed with the newly added items as desired. What do I have to do over and above calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` to trigger such a refresh programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is to use `ArrayAdapter` . so when you have new item to add to the list.. just call `adapter.add("your object")`, which will take care of calling `getView()` for the item added.

Note : This will add the item at last item in list view.

Comment: Hi Libin,Thanks for your answer,but Array Adapter is designed to display single item into the textview for each row,as this  constructor Signature says,                         ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects),                                                             while in my case I need row with multiple items ,like two Image,one text item

Comment: No. You can create any number of item for each row. Create a custom ArrayaAdapter and Override getView (). Its easy to do.